# How to get top and left position of the svg circle end point?

Tags: svg, geometry, position

Please can anybody to help me with this issue ? I need to get the end point of the circle to set it as axis for the line which should to direct to the end of the circle.

[image]

```
<?php
$radius = 130;
$circumference = (2 * pi() * $radius);
$dashoffsetStart = $circumference / 4;

$chart1 = ($circumference / 100) * 100;
$chart1Rest = $circumference - $chart1;
$dashoffset1 = $dashoffsetStart;

$chart2 = ($circumference / 100) * 34;
$chart2Rest = $circumference - $chart2;
$dashoffset2 = $dashoffsetStart + $chart1Rest;

$chart3 = ($circumference / 100) * 11;
$chart3Rest = $circumference - $chart3;
$dashoffset3 = $dashoffsetStart + $chart2Rest;

$chart4 = ($circumference / 100) * 52;
$chart4Rest = $circumference - $chart4;
$dashoffset4 = $dashoffsetStart + $chart3Rest + $chart2Rest;
```

$circleEndX = ????????????

$circleEndY = ????????????

```
?>
<div style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
    <svg class="shadow" width="300" height="300">
        <circle data-info="<?php echo $circumference; ?>" cx="150" cy="150" r="<?php echo $radius; ?>" stroke="grey" stroke-width="30" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="<?php echo $chart1 . ' ' . $chart1Rest; ?>" stroke-dashoffset="<?php echo $dashoffset1; ?>"></circle>
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="<?php echo $radius; ?>" stroke="red" stroke-width="30" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="<?php echo $chart2 . ' ' . $chart2Rest; ?>" stroke-dashoffset="<?php echo $dashoffset2; ?>"></circle>
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="<?php echo $radius; ?>" stroke="green" stroke-width="30" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="<?php echo $chart3 . ' ' . $chart3Rest; ?>" stroke-dashoffset="<?php echo $dashoffset3; ?>"></circle>
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="<?php echo $radius; ?>" stroke="orange" stroke-width="30" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="<?php echo $chart4 . ' ' . $chart4Rest; ?>" stroke-dashoffset="<?php echo $dashoffset4; ?>"></circle>
      
        <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="<?php echo $circleEndX; ?>" y2="<?php echo $circleEndY; ?>" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" marker-end="url(#triangle)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, don't post the code as image.

Comment: Sorry, my fault... I have added it like a code